# how to require "prawn/measurement_extensions" in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I wrote some demo code in ruby with prawn and want to move this code into my rails app
In the ruby code i use the measurement_extensions for prawn:

```
 require "prawn/measurement_extensions"
```

In my rails app i put the same line into my controller, but this provoces an error:

```
 cannot load such file -- prawn/measurement_extensions
```

So whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your rails ruby file inherit from Prawn::Document and require the extension within it e.g.

```
class NameOfClass < Prawn::Document
  require "prawn/measurement_extensions"
  #code
end
```

Answer (score 1):

From the prawn [documentation](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/wiki/Using-Prawn-in-Rails-3):

Add prawn to your Gemfile:

`gem 'prawn'`

Install:

`$ bundle install`

Create a file called `config/initializers/prawn.rb` and in it, add one of the following lines, depending on your Prawn version:

Prawn through 0.8.4:

`require "prawn/core"`

Prawn 0.9+ or git:

`require "prawn"`

Now, Prawn should be ready to go.